# how do I migrate my old magento(2.1.5) database to my new magento2.3.3

Tags: database, migration, magento2

How how do I migrate  my old magento(2.1.5)  database  to my new magento2.3.3 ?
my website run environment is :
centos 6.9
apache 2.4
php    7.2.24
mysql  5.7.28

my new magento 2.3.3 is a clean  project. no data ,no theme,no extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Migrate to Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3.3 (via composer)

You need to know your server requirement for migrating 2.3.3
[Server/System Requirement for Magento 2.3.3](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

Then, the second thing that you need to take the backup of database and your files from the server

#### Enable Maintenance Mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

#### Installing magento 2.3.3 Version

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

#### Update autoload

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
    "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
    "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
    "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
},}
```

You need to add "Zend\Mvc\Controller\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/" this line as mentioned above.

#### Composer Update for Our Changes

```
composer update
```

#### Clean Cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

#### Perform Setup and Schema Upgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

#### Disable Maintenance Mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

#### Checking Magento Version

```
php bin/magento --version
```

You can check detail information for migrating and upgrading [Magento2 Official Website for Command-Line Upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)