# Directly upgrade the Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3

Tags: php, magento, version, magento2, upgrade

Can we directly upgrade the Magento 2.1.5 to 2.3? Magento 2.1 supports the PHP version 5.6, 7 & 7.1 only and Magento 2.3 supports 7.1.3,7.2,7.3. Both support the different versions while readiness checks it always raised an error “**requires PHP ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement**”.

Anyone, can you please let me know the process of how to upgrade Magento 2.1 to 2.3. I am running this on my local window machine.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please check it.[Upgrade Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887185/how-do-i-migrate-my-old-magento2-1-5-database-to-my-new-magento2-3-3/58909487#58909487)

Answer (score 1):

Manually Magento Upgrade version 2.1 to 2.3 
Need PHP version is 7.2 
Copy all files of Magento 2.3 version and past to your magento2.1 need to overwrite all files
and Run Command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (if production mode)
bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work then you have to set the new version and try the update. If you want be sure that everything is correct you can first update so 2.2 that alle DB-migrations are made and then go to the next step. Normally composer always fetch the new packages and then make the database upgrades. So normally that should work.

You should make a backup before then you can try it again if it's not working.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: OKay. so there is no direct upgrade?

Comment: Try it ;) set the new PHP-Version and run the upgrade. If it's not working roll back.

Comment: I normally prefer to ugrade over both version to the sure that everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise to first update to the latest version of 2.2.x, then upgrade to 2.3.x. Reason being is that some setup/upgrade scripts may not be properly triggered executed, and you'll want to fully test the site on 2.2 before moving onto 2.3. Changes introduced in 2.3 could break your store, and it'll be hard to track down if either changes from 2.2 or 2.3 broke it. Fully testing your site on each version is advised, and this will most likely be quicker than going from 2.1 straight to 2.3.